# Slow VBA when creating new workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I've created a simple macro to filter some data, copy that to a new workbook, save that workbook and close that workbook.

I'm intending to use this on large datasets (where the initial dataset could be around 10000+ rows long), however on testing with 25 lines this is taking a VERY long time (i.e more than a few minutes). I am new to VBA and was wondering why this is running so slowly?

Note: I understand using Select can affect performance, however I don't think this is avoidable here?

Code below:

```
Sub Macro7()
'
' Macro7 Macro
'

'
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.Calculation = xlManual
 
 Dim cl As Range, rng As Range
 
 Set rng = Range("G3:G5")
 
 For Each cl In rng
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$D$25").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=cl.Value
        Cells.Select
        Selection.Copy
        Workbooks.Add
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        
        Dim Path1 As String
        Dim Path2 As String
        Dim myfilename As String

        Path1 = "C:\Users\name\Documents"
        Path2 = cl.Value
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path1 & "/" & Path2, FileFormat:=xlNormal
        
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        
        Windows("doc.xlsm").Activate
        Range("A1").Select
        
    Next cl
    
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Well `Cells.Select` and `Selection.Copy` can be simplified to `Cells.Copy`. Nothing too complicated here, but perhaps you could restrict the copy to just the used cells, not the entire sheet. Not sure what the bottleneck is.

Comment: Hmmm, I am new to VBA, but I'm not sure that would create any sort of issue on timing?

Comment: Have you thought about having a sheet on the original workbook where you can put the data temporarily and then export that single sheet as a CSV file. This may speed things up as you are not having to create a workbook each time, then copy the data, then save and close the new workbook!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slowness here was as a result of copying the entire sheet every time (1 million or so lines) - I defined a copy range and this cleared the slow problem

Answer (score 0):

You sure can avoid activate and select, we just should use variables:

```
Sub Macro7()
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     Application.Calculation = xlManual
     
     Dim twkb As Workbook
     Dim tws As Worksheet
     
     Dim ws As Worksheet
     Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
     
     Dim rng As Variant
     Dim cpyrng As Range
     
     rng = Range("G3:G5").Value
     
     Dim fltrng As Range
     Set fltrng = ws.Range("$A$2:$D$25")
    
     Dim i As Long
     For i = LBound(rng, 1) To UBound(rng, 1)
            fltrng.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=rng(i, 1)
            Set cpyrng = ws.Range("$A$1").Resize(fltrng.Rows.Count + 1, fltrng.Columns.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            
            Set twkb = Workbooks.Add
            Set tws = twkb.Worksheets(1)
            
            cpyrng.Copy tws.Range("A1")
            
            Dim Path1 As String
            Dim Path2 As String
            Dim myfilename As String
    
            Path1 = "C:\Users\name\Documents"
            Path2 = rng(i, 1)
            twkb.SaveAs Filename:=Path1 & "/" & Path2, FileFormat:=xlNormal
            
            twkb.Close
        Next i
        
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Note that this may not increase performance.  The bottle neck will be the creating and saving of the workbook.